# By considering the Cauchy–Riemann equations, or otherwise, find the set of complex numbers z at which F is complex differentiable.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

By considering the Cauchy–Riemann equations, or otherwise, find the set
of complex numbers z at which F is complex differentiable.

Where F is defined as $$F:\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$$ $$z\mapsto -|3z|^2$$

My attempt

$$-|3z|^2=-|9(x^2+2yxi-y^2)|$$ $$=-9x^2-18yxi-9y^2$$ or should it be equal to $$(9x^2-9y^2)+18xyi$$ Therefore for the first function i wrote above, $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=-18x$$ $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-18y$$ $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-18y$$ $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=-18x$$ Therefore $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$ and $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$ iff y=0 
Therefore the set of complex nuumbers z at which F is complex differentiable is $$Z=\{z=x+yi:\forall x\in \Bbb R, \forall y=0\}$$

for the second function above

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=18x$$ $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-18y$$ $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=18y$$ $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}-18x$$ Therefore $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$ and $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$ and thus differentiable $\forall x,y\in \Bbb R$ where $f'(z)=18x+18yi$
Can anyone confirm or correct my attempt for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Note that up to scalar multiplication, $g(z) = z \overline{z}$. If $g$ is differentiable at $c \neq 0$, then so is $\overline{z}$, but it is easy to see with the Cauchy-Riemann equations that $\overline{z}$ is nowhere differentiable, so there is no such $c$. However, one can check that $|z|^2$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations at $z = 0$.

Comment: wait what? is the question incorrect? or have i just expanded $-|3z|^2$ incorrectly?

Comment: @Gibberish Yes, you expanded $-3|z|^2$ incorrectly. It is just $-3(x^2 + y^2)$

Comment: may i ask why there is no i term? should it not be -3(x+iy)^2?

Comment: You are squaring the norm of $z$ (which is a real number), not $z$ itself!

Comment: so i calculated that $-|3z|^2=-9x^2-9y^2$ $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=-18x^2$$ and $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$$ $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0$$ and finally \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=-18y^2 therefore the cauchy riemann equations hold $$\forall x,y \in \Bbb R$$ ? is this correct? and if so what would the set of complex numbers be would it be just $$z=\{x+iy\},\forall x=y\in \Bbb R$$?

Comment: You calculated the partial derivatives incorrectly. $-|3z|^2$ is a real function-- it doesn't even have an imaginary part. So you need to find points where both partial derivatives of its real part vanishes.